# Не получается получить данные о UDP соединениях с помощью GetExtendedUdpTable

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

Есть следующий код:

```
    private struct MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID
    {
        public uint dwLocalAddr;
        public uint dwLocalPort;
        public uint dwOwningPid;
    }
   enum UDP_TABLE_CLASS
    {
        UDP_TABLE_BASIC,
        UDP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE,
        UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID
    }

    const uint ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
    const uint NO_ERROR = 0;
    private const uint AF_INET = 2;
    private const uint AF_INET6 = 23;

    [DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern uint GetExtendedUdpTable(IntPtr pTcpTable,
       ref int pdwSize,
       bool bOrder,
       uint ulAf,
       UDP_TABLE_CLASS TableClass,
       uint Reserved
       )
       ;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID[] ms = GetUdpTableForEachProcess();
            foreach (MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID m in ms )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.dwLocalPort);
            }
        }
    }
    static MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID[] GetUdpTableForEachProcess()
    {
        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        int buffSize = 0;
        uint dwError;

        dwError = GetExtendedUdpTable(ptr, ref buffSize, false, AF_INET, UDP_TABLE_CLASS.UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID, 0);

        if (dwError != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffSize);

        dwError = GetExtendedUdpTable(ptr, ref buffSize, false, AF_INET, UDP_TABLE_CLASS.UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID, 0);

        if (dwError != NO_ERROR)
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            return null;
        }

        int count = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr);
        IntPtr ptrRead = ptr + sizeof(int);
        int sz = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID));
        MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID[] mtop = new MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID[count];

        for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++)
        {
            mtop[i] = (MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptrRead, typeof(MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID));
            ptrRead += sz;
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return mtop;


    }
```

И вместо того, чтобы вернуть мне порт, оно возвращает значения вида 0 0 0 *куча цифр* 0 0 0. Тоже самое и с PID. Причем с GetExtendedTcpTable все работает отлично. Все структуры и перечисления точно правильные, так как взяты с MSDN. Null нигде и никто не возвращает. Есть идеи, товарищи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Все структуры и перечисления точно правильные

Так то нет. В *UDP_TABLE_CLASS* порядок неверный, должно быть:

```
enum UDP_TABLE_CLASS
{
    UDP_TABLE_BASIC,            
    UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID,
    UDP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE,
}
```

Comment: а как преобразовать dwLocalAddr к обычному виду IP? IPAddress не помогает.

Comment: @OlegLylok влияет. Значения enum транслируются в int. Если значение явно не присвоено, оно вычисляется в зависимости от порядка.

Comment: я уже понял, что чушь сказал, можете, пожалуйста, посмотреть на мой небольшой вопрос выше?

Comment: @OlegLylok `(new System.Net.IPAddress((long)m.dwLocalAddr)).ToString()` - как-то так

Comment: спасибо вам большое